# Searching Elasticsearch with different query phrases

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I am quite new to elasticsearch so I am struggling about with this:

I have an elasticsearch index with a property called title, if for example I have the following values on this property :

```
"Questions To The First Minister" {1}

"First person to speak"  {2}

"First to speak will be Minister Dave"  {3}
```

On my site I have a text box where the user could enter the following phrases:

```
"First Minster"

which should return {1}

First Minister

which should return {1} {2} {3}

First+Minister 

which should return {1} {3}
```

Currently the only way I can think of doing this would be to have 3 different queries based on what the user is entering into the text box:

for the first one:

```
{
  query:{
     bool:{
      must:[
            {
            match:{
               title:{
                      query: First Minister,
                      type: phrase
                     }
                  }
            }
           ]
          }
        }
  min_score: 1
}
```

Second one:

```
{
  query:{
    bool:{
      must:[{
       match:{
         terms: {
         title:[
          "first",
          "minister"
              ]}
             }]
           }
          }
}
```

Third one I haven't really thought too deeply about as my PM as only just told me of this scenario.

The question is:

Is there a better way to do this, which could be achieved in a single query to ES or is it the "correct" way to do it, by looking at the entered input and then changing the query based on that?

Answer (score 0):

I Think i might have a solution to this.

I am posting this here incase anyone else looks for it (and maybe someone can tell me if this is an okay way to do it)

I think i can do it using just 1 query using the query_string query.

if i search for "\"first minister"\" its returning {1}

if i search for "first AND Minster" its returning {3}

and "first OR minister" its returning {1} {2} {3}

Comment: great solution buddy...thanks for leaving the rest of us hanging.